# Separate values from array

Tags: iphone, xcode

This string response i am getting from server.

```
2001,wooza,0420224346,J Wratt ,+61417697070,2013-55-1803-55-54.jpg,No<br />2002,wooza,0420224346,J Wratt ,+61417697070,2013-56-1803-56-17.jpg,No<br />2003,testing,9894698946,ggh hjj,9894598945,2013-11-1811-11-40.jpg,Yes<br />
```

I separate each record through `"br"` and stored it in a array.How do i access `(2013-55-1803-55-54.jpg)` value from array.

Answer (score 0):

You can get through `objectAtIndex` method.

Alrenatively its better you keep the all the related data of your custom class and storing that in array.

Most of the times you will need more than one value during display. In that case, just get the object from array and show related info through object reference.

Answer (score 0):

Take comma separated strings from an intended element in a different array and use NSPredicate to get the string containing .jpg in it.